# HTML button getting submitted by default to next php page although not clicked

Tags: php, html, button, textbox

I have created two .php webpages. The first page has the below code:

## sample1.php

```
<?php 
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form action=\"sample2.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<table width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><td width='30%'><font size='5' color='#003399'>Message 1</font></td><td align='center' width='50%'><font size='5' color='#003399'>Message 2</font></td></tr>";
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    if($i == 0)
    {
            echo "<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EAEAEA\" style=\"color:#003399\">$i</td><td align='center'><input type='text' name='tarea'></td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr><td bgcolor=\"#EAEAEA\" style=\"color:#003399\">$i</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr><td><div>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"version\" value=\"ant\"> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"version\" value=\"bat\"> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"version\" value=\"cat\"> &nbsp; &nbsp;";
    echo "</div></tr></td>";
}   
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

The second page is as follows:

## sample2.php

```
<?php 
$vers = $_POST['version'];
$area = $_POST['tarea'];
echo "This is selected value: $vers<br>";
echo "this is textbox value: $area<br>";
?>
```

When I click a button on sample1.php, it gets passed to the next page as expected. However, when I enter a value in the textbox and press enter, the first button also gets submitted by default along with the textbox value.

Expected Output:

If a button is clicked on sample1.php, the same should be passed to sample2.php. Next if a value is entered in the textarea on sample1.php, only that value should be passed to sample2.php and not the button value.

Thanks,

Maddy

Comment: you need to check with `if(condition == x)`

Comment: you should put them in separate forms

Comment: if i add 2 separate forms, how can i display the text box and the buttons in the same page aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to check if the submit was set and equal to the given value for the inputs.

This is but one way of doing this. There are other ways.

```
if(isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] == 'ant'){

$vers = $_POST['version'];

// ant was fired

}

if(isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] == 'bat'){

$vers = $_POST['version'];

// bat was fired

}

if(isset($_POST['version']) && $_POST['version'] == 'cat'){

$vers = $_POST['version'];

// cat was fired

}
```

Sidenote: I would remove those `&nbsp; &nbsp;` though. They could have adverse effects in PHP. The semi-colon is an end of statement character.

---

**Edit:**

Example of a `foreach` and passing key values:

```
$var = "";
foreach($_POST['version'] as $key => $value) {
   if(!empty($value)) {
     $var .= $key. "='".$value."',";
   }
}
```

Comment: But my values, ("ant", "bat" and "cat") are not limited to 3. They will keep increasing as I need to add more values and in that case my if statements will also increase right?

Comment: why not save some coding time by just checking if `$_POST['version']` isset, then inside of that function check foreach version type

Comment: @Maddy Then you'd need to set them up as arrays and implode on them.

Comment: @rackemup420 exactly what I was getting at. The OP would need to treat those values as arrays.